# Iterate over record fields

Tags: delphi, for-loop, records

How to iterate over the record fields of G1-G4 with a for loop?

```
  TrFireGroup = record   
    idx: integer; 
    G1: integer;
    G2: integer;
    G3: integer;
    G4: integer;
    FGroup: integer;
    MstIdx: integer; 
    Status: byte;
    procedure Clear;
  end;
```

Comment: By and large you don't. Why are you asking? Context would help.

Comment: The best approach - combine semantically close fields to array `G: array[1..4] of Integer;`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought it would be more elegant than writing four fleshy if statement, but i take your advice. The whole idea was smelling from the first time. (:

Comment: @MBo yes i will do that, thank You. That way the fields are not that exact but its ok.

Comment: You can also declare that fields as both array and seperate using variant record part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to maintain the existing record interface structure for compatibility you could use properties to do this.  Storing the values in an array allows you to enumerate them and you can define properties with the existing names to access the values directly in the existing way.

```
program Project1;    
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}   

type
  TGArray = array[0..3] of integer;
  TrFireGroup = record
    private
      FGArr : TGArray;
    public
      idx: integer;
      FGroup: integer;
      MstIdx: integer;
      Status: byte;         
      property G1 : integer read FGArr[0] write FGArr[0];
      property G2 : integer read FGArr[1] write FGArr[1];
      property G3 : integer read FGArr[2] write FGArr[2];
      property G4 : integer read FGArr[3] write FGArr[3];
      property GArray : TGArray read FGArr;
  end;

var
  LFireGroup : TrFireGroup;
  j : integer;
begin
  LFireGroup.G1 := 1;
  LFireGroup.G2 := 3;
  LFireGroup.G3 := 5;
  LFireGroup.G4 := 7;

  for j in LFireGroup.GArray do
    WriteLn(j);    
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If you need the record layout to be binary compatible (for whatever reason) you can give up some of the tidyness and rearrange things

```
  TrFireGroup = record        
    idx: integer;
    GArray : TGArray;
    FGroup: integer;
    MstIdx: integer;
    Status: byte;
    procedure Clear;         
    property G1 : integer read GArray[0] write GArray[0];
    property G2 : integer read GArray[1] write GArray[1];
    property G3 : integer read GArray[2] write GArray[2];
    property G4 : integer read GArray[3] write GArray[3];          
  end;
```

Leaving `GArray` as a public field also lets you do indexed writes (whereas this is not possible with it as a plain property) - ie :

```
for i := Low(TGArray) to High(TGArray) do
    LFireGroup.GArray[i] := 2*i;
```

Alternatively, if you can give up `for/in` semantics you can define the array as default property and reference the record directly :

```
  TrFireGroup = record
    private
      FGArr : TGArray;
      procedure SetG(index:integer; Value:integer);
      function GetG(index:integer) : integer;
    public
      property G1 : integer read FGArr[0] write FGArr[0];
      property G2 : integer read FGArr[1] write FGArr[1];
      property G3 : integer read FGArr[2] write FGArr[2];
      property G4 : integer read FGArr[3] write FGArr[3];
      property GArray[index:integer]:integer read GetG write SetG; default;
  end;

procedure TrFireGroup.SetG(index:integer; Value:integer);
begin
  FGArr[index] := Value;
end;

function TrFireGroup.GetG(index: Integer) : integer;
begin
  result := FGArr[index];
end;
```

which lets you do :

```
for i := Low(TGArray) to High(TGArray) do
  LFireGroup[i] := 2*i;

for i := Low(TGArray) to High(TGArray) do
  WriteLn(LFireGroup[i]);
```

Comment: nice tip your usage of properties

Answer (score 4):

This might not be a good idea, but it is possible.

```
procedure Test();
var
  i: Integer;
  rec: TrFireGroup;
  GPtr: PInteger;
  value: Integer;
begin
  // Initialize rec ...

  // Get pointer to first G? field
  GPtr := @rec.G1;

  // Loop over G fields
  for i := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    // Use value G? field here...
    // For example: value := GPtr^;

    // Increment pointer, thus moving it with four bytes.
    Inc(GPtr);
  end;
end;
```

- First get a pointer (`GPtr`) to the first field in the rec.
- Then, we use the value by dereferencing the pointer (`GPtr^`).
- Finally, increment the pointer to next value (`Inc(GPtr)`).
  Note that increment is moving the pointer with the size of the type that is being referenced.

  And as we are using a pointer to Integer (`PInteger`), `Inc` moves the pointer with `SizeOf(Integer)`, which advances to the next field in the record.

Again, this is not good practice.

Pointer arithmetic is overkill in this case, unless you have hundreds fields in the record (which is very very rare), but this is one way to do it if you really need.

Just for reference, there is a very detailed and quality explanation on pointers in Delphi and pointer arithmetic here:

> - [Addressing pointers by Rudy Velthuis](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html)

Comment: Thank You quasoft, but as its not really recommended im hesitate to accept Your answer. What is the sanctified way? Accept or just upvote, or none of them?

Comment: Accept only the answer that you consider is the right solution for your case. Upvote answers that are correct and/or useful. Downvote answers that are not bringing any value and not useful/wrong.

Comment: Isn't this approach `$ALIGN` sensitive?

Comment: Good catch, the record should either be packed or alignment should be off/set to one.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, if you don't need binary compatibility then the easiest option is to use a [variant record](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records):

```
TrFireGroup = record
  idx: integer;
  FGroup: integer;
  MstIdx: integer;
  Status: byte;
  procedure Clear;
  case Integer of
    0: (G1: integer; G2: integer; G3: integer; G4: integer);
    1: (GArr: array[0..3] of integer);
end;
```

This is the equivalent of the old Delphi `absolute` keyword. Both the array and the four G? variables share the same spot in memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a recent Delphi version and only need the current values of G1..G4 (i.e. not write to them) you can also use this approach:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  fg: TrFireGroup;
  arr: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  ...
  arr := [fg.G1, fg.G2, fg.G3, fg.G4];
  for I in arr do begin
    Writeln(I);
  end;
  ...
end;
```